# How to make construction client friendly when Exteneding DialogFragment?

Tags: java, android, oop

I'm extending DialogFragment.  I wanted to use a customer listener because onDateSet was causing numerous issues.  (Not being able to cancel selection nicely, being called twice on some devices, not working at all on others.)

However the problem is my class isn't very client friendly.  As it stands somebody might instantiate my class and not set the required listener.
As it's written the client that uses my code would have to know to create the class and then set the listener separately.

What can I do to make the proper use of this class more obvious to the user?
Anything I can think of doing involves changing the default constructor which Android does not allow me to do.

```
public class DatePickerDialogFragment extends DialogFragment implements OnDateSetListener {
DatePickerDialog dp;
DatePickerDialogFragmentListener listener;
final Calendar calendar;
public DatePickerDialogFragment(){
    calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
}

public void setDatePickerDialogFragmentListener(DatePickerDialogFragmentListener dialogFragmentListener ){
    listener = dialogFragmentListener;
}

public  void setInitialDate(int year, int month, int day){
    calendar.set(year, month, day);
}

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    dp = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);

    DialogInterface.OnClickListener okClickListener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            if (listener != null){ // if the listener has been set correctly.
                try {
                    Field mDatePickerField = dp.getClass().getDeclaredField("mDatePicker");
                    mDatePickerField.setAccessible(true);
                    DatePicker datePicker = (DatePicker) mDatePickerField.get(dialog);
                    listener.okClicked(datePicker, datePicker.getYear(), datePicker.getMonth(), datePicker.getDayOfMonth());
                } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {

                } 
                catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {

                } 
                catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                }
            }
        }
    };
    DialogInterface.OnClickListener cancelClickListener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

        }
    };
    dp.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "Cancel", cancelClickListener);
    dp.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "Ok", okClickListener);
    return dp;
}

@Override
public void onDateSet(DatePicker arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
    // Not using because it is inconsistant accross devices and O/S's

}
public interface DatePickerDialogFragmentListener {
    public void okClicked(DatePicker datePicker, int year, int month, int day);
    public void cancelClicked(); 
}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general paradigm for this is to provide an interface in your Fragment which the host Activity *must* implement. For example:

```
public class DatePickerDialogFragment extends DialogFragment implements OnDateSetListener {
    DatePickerDialog dp;
    DatePickerDialogFragmentListener mListener;
    final Calendar mCalendar;

    public DatePickerDialogFragment(){
        calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        if (activity instanceof DatePickerDialogFragmentListener) {
            mListener = (DatePickerDialogFragmentListener) activity;
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("The Activity hosting this " 
                    + "Fragment must implement DatePickerDialogFragmentListener";
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        mListener = null;
    }

    private void fireOnOkClicked () {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onOkClicked();
        }
    }

    private void fireOnCancelClicked () {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onCancelClicked();
        }
    }

    public void setInitialDate(int year, int month, int day){
        calendar.set(year, month, day);
    }

    public interface DatePickerDialogFragmentListener {
        public void okClicked(DatePicker datePicker, int year, int month, int day);
        public void cancelClicked(); 
    }
}
```

In this way, they are forced to implement the interface, otherwise the application will throw an exception. It also prevents memory leaks; using a setter to set the Activity as the listener for the fragment would leak that activity once the device is rotated, and if that listener updated the UI, those updates would mysteriously stop happening because of a reference to an old activity.

Comment: Thanks so much.  What should I do should I need to have 2 of these dialog on the same activity?  Wrap them in classes implementing DatePickerDialogFragmentListener?

Comment: Ah, that's where it gets complicated. So, what you could do is also pass in an argument for some identifier, and pass that identifier back in the callback.

Comment: Thanks again.  I might have to rethink this.  I wanted to make a customer compound View containing a button that launched this dialog, but it's starting to sound like that might be bad.

Comment: I think it'd be alright this way, as long as you enforce that they provide an identifier, it'd be no more complicated than using startActivityForResult.

Comment: I get the "identifier" concept, but View is not s subclass of Activity, so it would defeat the purpose of my custom View if the Activity hosting my custom view had to handle the callbacks.  Or am I missing something obvious again?  I just re-read this, it sounds rude, I'm not trying to be.

Comment: Oh sorry, I misunderstood you. Maybe, you would be better off using a standard dialog instead of a DialogFragment in that case? Fragments are pretty much expected to have tight ties to their activities. Was the custom view supposed to handle the interface events too?

Comment: Another thought, if that's the case, would be to use an activity instead of a dialog fragment, and just use a translucent floating activity theme.

Comment: The custom view can save it's own state, so if the screen rotates (Rotation currently locked but may be enabled later) the data is maintained.  If the dialog is open and something happens, I don't mind if the dialog does not come back up.

Comment: If that's the case, I'd just use a standard dialog. A lot less overhead worry about, and the View itself could offer an interface for the OK and Cancel buttons, similar to an OnClickListener.

Comment: That sounds reasonable. Thanks so much for your help.  I don't have the rep to vote you up, or I would.

Comment: Don't worry about it, I'm just glad to help. Good luck with your project. :)